# Select metakey values from WP database only where posts are published (two tables)

Tags: sql, wordpress, sqlite

I am trying to select metakey values from wordpress database like this:

```
global $wpdb;

$r = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
     SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
     WHERE meta_key = 'cast' 
 ") );
```

This code works perfectly well except it is showing results for unpublished posts as well. For that Reason I have tried to add aditional parameter from post table which is marked as "publish".  I have tried to query database like this but it is not working:

```
 $r = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "

      SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
      FROM wp_postmeta
      LEFT JOIN wp_posts
      ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
      WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cast' AND wp_posts.post_status ='publish'


") );
```

Comment: Move your `AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'` section to your `ON` clause for your `LEFT JOIN`.  By including it in the `WHERE` clause, it is transforming the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I have tried to move it  like this :    ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
                                      AND wp_posts.post_status ='publish'
                                      WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cast'      but it is still not working.

Comment: @Siyual I think he does want and INNER JOIN because he says he only wants "published" results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer by my self. I don't know if it is the best solution but it accomplish what I need. So, for everybody else looking for an answer here is my code that works:

```
global $wpdb;

      $r = $wpdb->get_col( "

            SELECT key1.meta_value
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta key1
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts key2
            ON key1.post_id = key2.ID 
            AND key2.post_status ='publish'
            WHERE key1.meta_key = 'cast' 

      " );
```